# not able to get filtered count of ng-repeat object with pagination

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to implement pagination to the filtered results of the ng-repeat object. As a syntax rule alias can only be applied to the end and due this I'm not able to get the correct count of the repeater object.

```
<md-card class="blur-box">
    <md-input-container>
        <label>Search</label>
        <input ng-change="updated()" type="text" ng-model="search" md-maxlength="10">
    </md-input-container>
    <md-table-container>
        <table md-table md-row-select multiple ng-model="selected">
            <thead md-head md-order="query.order">
                <!-- <tr>{{query.order}}</tr> -->
                <tr md-row>
                    <th md-column md-numeric md-order-by="key">Roll Number</th>
                    <th md-column md-order-by="value.firstName">firstName</th>
                    <th md-column md-order-by="value.lastName">lastName</th>
                    <th md-column md-order-by="value.email">email</th>
                    <th md-column md-order-by="value.dob">dob</th>
                    <th md-column md-order-by="value.college">college</th>
                    <th md-column md-order-by="value.course">course</th>
                    <th md-column md-order-by="value.status">status</th>
                    <th md-column md-order-by="value.note">note</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody md-body>
                <tr md-row md-select="student" md-select-id="key" ng-repeat="student in students | filter: search | orderBy: query.order | limitTo: query.limit : (query.page -1) * query.limit as fStudents"> 
                    <td md-cell>{{student.key}}</td>
                    <td md-cell>{{student.value.firstName}}</td>
                    <td md-cell>{{student.value.lastName}}</td>
                    <td md-cell>{{student.value.email}}</td>
                    <td md-cell>{{student.value.dob}}</td>
                    <td md-cell>{{student.value.college}}</td>
                    <td md-cell>{{student.value.course}}</td>
                    <td md-cell>{{student.value.status}}</td>
                    <td md-cell>{{student.value.note}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </md-table-container>
    <md-table-pagination md-limit="query.limit" md-limit-options="limitOptions" md-page="query.page" md-total="{{fStudents.length}}" md-page-select="true" md-on-paginate="logPagination"></md-table-pagination>
</md-card>
```

For instance in above code I've about 27 objects initially. But due to pagination the Count({{fStudents.length}}) always say 5 unless the object.length is less than 5.

Need help to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use filterResult.  Change your ng-repeat to:

```
ng-repeat="student in (filterResult = (students | filter: search | orderBy: query.order | limitTo: query.limit : (query.page -1) * query.limit as fStudents))"
```

Then change the md-total to:

```
md-total="{{search ? filterResult.length : fStudents.length}}"
```